# Converting a time string to append with DateTime object

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan, time-format

I have a time string as `12:48 AM`. I want to convert this string into `TimeSpan` to append with `DateTime` Object. Currently I am trying the following snippets.

```
string format = "dd/MM/yyyy";
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateValue, format, provider);

string timeFormate = "H:mm AM";
string timeValue = "12:48 AM";
var time = TimeSpan.ParseExact(timeValue,timeFormate,provider);
DateTime launchDate = date + time;
```

I am getting

> *Input string was not in a correct format*

exception at line

```
 var time = TimeSpan.ParseExact(timeValue,timeFormate,provider);
```

Please suggest me how to convert my specified string into time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to parse that time into `DateTime` and then simply extract the `TimeOfDay` out of it when appending to the original date:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

namespace Sample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dateValue = "10/03/1987";
            var date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateValue, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            var timeValue = "12:48 AM";
            var time = DateTime.ParseExact(timeValue, "h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            var dateTime = date + time.TimeOfDay;

            Console.WriteLine(date);
            Console.WriteLine(time);
            Console.WriteLine(dateTime);
        }
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
3/10/1987 12:00:00 AM
11/12/2014 12:48:00 AM
3/10/1987 12:48:00 AM
```

Answer (score 3):

You can parse it to `DateTime` and use it's [`TimeOfDay` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the time:

```
DateTime time = DateTime.ParseExact("12:48 AM", "h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime launchDate = date + time.TimeOfDay;
```

Note that i've also changed the format string since you need `tt` for the AM/PM designator.

Answer (score 1):

`12:48 AM` is not a [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.TimeSpan%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it is a time part of a [`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You need to parse it to `DateTime`, not `TimeSpan`.

You can use to add [`.TimeOfDay` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of your time and add it to `date`. This property returns only time part of your `DateTime` as a `TimeSpan`.

```
string timeValue = "12:48 AM";
var time = DateTime.ParseExact(timeValue, "h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime launchDate = date + time.TimeOfDay;
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this Page from MSDN, this could help u

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992370(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a DateTime object

```
 string timeValue = "10:48 AM";
 string timeFormate = "h:mm tt";
 var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(timeValue, timeFormate, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

edit:
if you want to add a timespan to a given DateTime object you should skip the "AM/PM"

```
string timeValue = "2:30";
DateTime launchTime = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan timeSpan;
if (TimeSpan.TryParse(timeValue, out timeSpan))
{
   launchTime = launchTime.Add(timeSpan);
}
```

BR